# How to assign Sorted DataView to DataTable with keeping Sorted State using C#?

Tags: c#, sorting, datatable, dataview

I have a `DataView` with `Sort` applied on it. I am not able to assign/copy the `Sorted` State of `DataView` to `DataTable`.

Sort the DataView with Column 'Distance':

```
DataTable table=GetData();
DataView view = table.DefaultView;
view.Sort = "Distance";
```

this works fine.

But, **when i assign this `DataView` to `DataTable` it** **LOOSES THE SORTED STATE**.

```
DataTable dt = (view.Table);
```

This looses the Sorted State of `DataView`
Any idea? 
Please correct my  code if something wrong.

**So, i want to assign/copy the Sorted `DataView` to `DataTable` without loosing the Sorted State.**

Comment: is table and dt same tables?

Comment: no! added more please see...!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `view.ToTable()` instead of `view.Table`. Please see below snippet

```
DataTable table=GetData();
DataView view = table.DefaultView;
view.Sort = "Distance";

DataTable dt = view.ToTable();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can directly get dataview propery in the Datatable itself.

```
DataTable table=GetData();
table.DefaultView.Sort="Distance";
table=table.DefaultView.ToTable();
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a really efficient way to write a one line sort that maintains the sorting of the `DataView` in the parent `DataTable`.

```
table = new DataView(table, "", "Distance",
                     DataViewRowState.CurrentRows).ToTable()
```